# Choose image from app, and make my app appear in list (complete action using)?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want users to see my app in the list when they are selecting an image from another app.

Lets take the Facebook app for example. You can select an image to attach to a post, which brings up the "Complete action using" dialog that normally just contains "Gallery". I want my app to appear in this list.

(Most similar questions are regarding picking an image from my own app, which is not at all what I wish to accomplish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a intent filter to the activity that you wish to start. The correct intent for Facebook is PICK:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

However, this does not cover the same scenario for the Tumblr app, which apparently uses some other intent for the same type of action (attaching a photo).